# QGIS2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 cannot see the hints when hover over

Tags: qgis-2

I am running QGIS2.0 on Ubuntu server 12.04. After installing some libraries for Grass and Orfeo toolbox (I don't remember exactly which ones), I cannot see the hints when i hover over a menu bar or a layer. I can see only the colored frame of the hint without the text. Has anyone experienced something similar?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a missing font or a theme issue.  QGIS does not follow typical desktop theming (except for the title bar).

QGIS is based on QT and therefore you would can use QT Configuration tool to adjust the settings.

Select your theme in QT Configuration tool and check that your font and your colors make sense and are present.

QGIS also has a theme/style selection under options (In 1.8 -> Settings -> Options -> General), but I find the configuration tool more responsive (and testable)

Comment: Thank you very much!! I tried again the QT configuration tool and it worked. :)